# Vector image mangled on Lollipop and newer devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-vectordrawable

I'm loving the VectorDrawable in Android, but some of the Drawables imported from svg are not displayed properly in Android studio and Lollipop+ devices. However, the generated PNGs are fine, so the drawable is displayed correctly on older versions of android.
Interestingly enough, the vector drawables are rendered correctly on Android N preview.

My current workaround is getting the generated pngs, moving them to corresponding `drawable-dpi` folders and deleting the vector.

Sample vector drawable:

```
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="160dp"
android:height="160dp"
android:viewportHeight="161.80794"
android:viewportWidth="161.80745">
<path
    android:fillColor="#fff"
    android:pathData="M81.9,90.59c11.32,0 20.53,-11.26 20.53,-25.1 0,-13.84 -9.21,-25.1 -20.53,-25.1 -5.58,0 -10.8,2.68 -14.69,7.54a28.09,28.09 0,0 0,-5.84 17.56C61.37,79.33 70.58,90.59 81.9,90.59ZM81.9,44.97c8.8,0 15.97,9.21 15.97,20.53 0,11.32 -7.17,20.53 -15.97,20.53s-15.97,-9.21 -15.97,-20.53C65.93,54.18 73.1,44.97 81.9,44.97ZM97.87,86.03a2.28,2.28 0,1 0,0 4.56,15.99 15.99,0 0,1 15.97,15.97 2.29,2.29 0,0 1,-2.28 2.28h-59.31a2.29,2.29 0,0 1,-2.28 -2.28A15.99,15.99 0,0 1,65.94 90.59a2.28,2.28 0,0 0,0 -4.56A20.55,20.55 0,0 0,45.4 106.56a6.85,6.85 0,0 0,6.84 6.84h59.31A6.85,6.85 0,0 0,118.4 106.56,20.56 20.56,0 0,0 97.87,86.03Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#fff"
    android:pathData="M80.9,161.81A80.9,80.9 0,1 1,161.81 80.9,81 81,0 0,1 80.9,161.81ZM80.9,4.32A76.59,76.59 0,1 0,157.49 80.9,76.67 76.67,0 0,0 80.9,4.32Z" />
</vector>
```

Is there a proper solution to fix these drawables, like a converter? Or at least to exclude the vector from build automatically and just just pngs for all API levels?

Comment: try [this](http://pastebin.com/DwPYFKJD) to get the `VectorDrawableCompat`

Comment: That works on Marshmallow, but crashes on KitKat:  `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_favourite_grey.png from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f0200a5`

Comment: you want to use <vector> drawables so what is `ic_favourite_grey.png` doing there? just use vectors, dont generate any pngs

Comment: Yeah, good point. I haven't disabled generating pngs. The solution works, however it's more awkward loading the images programmatically, but at least they render correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Oh you have two choices: custom ImageView/TextView or whatever view you are using or modify vector compat library and remove the first "if" in create() method